# Can I fine tune GPT-3?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transformer, gpt

Can anyone fine-tune the GPT-3 model on commodity hardware without GPU?

- What I meant is can we fine tune available GPT-3 equivalent models?
- For example, we have only access to GPT-J.
- Can we fine-tune GPT-J with commodity hardware or lets say with only basic GPU such as 1with one RTX 3080.

Can we fine-tune these models (not training from scratch)?

Or will it need high-end infrastructure with GPUs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weights of GPT-3 are not public. You can fine-tune it but only through the interface provided by OpenAI. In any case, GPT-3 is too large to be trained on CPU.

About other similar models, like GPT-J, they would not fit on a RTX 3080, because it has 10/12Gb of memory and GPT-J takes 22+ Gb for float32 parameters. It should possible to fine-tune some special versions that use int8 precision, like [this one](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14839).

Comment: @neo sorry for my ambiguous question. Updated with further detail.

Comment: I updated my answer with the new information you provided.